# Electrons in propulsion?

Tags: space-travel, spaceships

The thought occurred to me that if propulsion in space required that a ship push mass behind it somehow, then perhaps an engine could be constructed which operated by releasing electrons and accelerating them.

Assuming this technology is to be put on relatively small (car to small airplane size) spacecraft, is it feasible? How much energy would it consume and how fast/maneuverable would it be?

EDIT: There seems to have been much confusion. The technology I propose here is not an ion thruster as it releases electrons. Ion thrusters propel the craft by emitting ions, which are not solely electrons. I hope the downvoters may reconsider.

Comment: Google is your usual best friend: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ion_thruster and you want to push ions since they are more massive than electrons

Comment: This is an engineering question that was already discussed on physics and space stacks.

Comment: I don't get the down votes. Most questions here show a lack of research effort. This one is answerable and based on a concept that shows the op knows some basics. One of the better questions here, it just happens to be something reasonable. It would only be off topic also if he asked specifically about existing drives. +1 for me, one of the more valid questions I've seen lately

Comment: Where do you get the electrons?  Why does that source not produce nuclei as well?  Or do you have nuclei left over?  What do you do with them if so?  " How much energy would it consume and how fast/maneuverable would it be?"  This requires knowledge of how it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As L.Dutch mentioned in comments, this is called an ion thruster, and have the advantage of requiring a very low reaction mass because they accelerate the electrons so fast. The disadvantage is that an electron is extremely light weight, so they have a rather low amount of 'thrust.'

However, you haven't specified what else is on your small spacecraft. If we have a handwaviumly good reactor, then we can put *a lot* of power into our ion thruster, and it will output more thrust.

Let's run some numbers:
According to wikipedia, 1-7Kw of power produces 25-250mNm of thrust. Let's take the low end of the scale, assuming that 1kw produces 25mNm.
Let's take an A4W reactor from an aircraft carrier and wire it in. These reactors produce 500MW of thermal energy. Assuming a 100% efficient conversion into electricity (impossible), we are producing 500,000 Kw * 0.250 Nm / 1Kw = 125kNm.

That's quite a bit of push actually, more than I thought. I couldn't find out how much an A4W reactor weighs, but it's probably about 100 tonnes. (It wasn't engineered for spaceflight, Ok?). Ignoring issues with running ship-based reactors in space, this means that an ion engine strapped to an A4W engine will accelerate at about 1.25m/s^2. That's not enough to escape earth's gravity well, but it quite a manoeuvrable spacecraft by modern standards - especially because it can accelerate like that for 20 years without refueling. It couldn't quite take off from the moon (1.6m/s^2), but accelerates faster than an elevator car (~1m/s^2).

If we allow more advanced reactor technology (or a modern reactor designed for space-travel) then you could possibly get more power-to-weight reactors and better acceleration.

---

Something else worth mentioning is that metals are held together by electrons. If you are throwing them out the back of your engine to move your spacecraft, you may run out of them on your spacecraft! This will eventually result in the metals weakening. I haven't done the math on how long this takes, but it may be a concern for longer voyages.

You also have to worry about electricity discharging when your spacecraft touches another - both will have changed electric potential at different rates, so there will be a voltage between them. This could actually be pretty cool, as a spacecraft descending into an atmosphere could sanely be described as "surrounded by bolts of lightning" as the static dissipates.

Comment: 1.25 m/s is a speed, not an acceleration. Did you mean 1.25 m/s^2? (Which means that the speed increases by "1.25 meters per second" per second.)

Comment: I also think that you've got at least some of your comparative numbers wrong; Earth's Moon's escape velocity would be more like 1.6 km/s than 1.6 m/s, and it doesn't really make any significant difference how fast you gain it, only that you do.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling It actually does make difference how fast you gain escape velocity. Or orbital speed. Thrust has to first overcome gravitational pull, only thrust above that contributes to gaining escape or orbital velocity. The less time it takes, the less fuel is wasted on counteracting gravitation. It's called [gravity drag](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravity_drag). On one extreme, rocket with local power to weight of 1 will never lift off, no matter how much propellant is expended, on other extreme rocket with infinite PTW will expend minimum possible value.

Comment: @Miech True in what you're saying, but I think you miss the larger point of my comment, which was that to say that you need 1.6 m/s to take off from the Moon doesn't really make sense. Of course you technically *can* take off from any celestial body with any initial net acceleration greater than zero followed by a period of net zero acceleration (climbing out of the gravity well at a constant, positive, non-zero speed), but that doesn't mean that it would be a *good* way to do it (as you point out).

Comment: Sorry, I did mean acceleration: m/s^2